# Attach conditionalPanel to specific button instead of general page load in Shiny app (R)

Tags: r, shiny

I have a conditionalPanel that I am using to show the progress of a calculation on one of my Shiny pages.  It calls some javascript to show the time progress of the calculation.

ui.R

```
 conditionalPanel("updateBusy() || $('html').hasClass('shiny-busy')",
 id='progressIndicator',
 "Calculating...",
 div(id='progress',includeHTML("timer.js")))
```

This fires whenever any button or selector is used on the page.  In other words, anything that causes the page to reload activates the conditionalPanel. How can I make it so that it only activates for a specific selector or button.  I am assuming it needs to be tied into an "isolate" expression or something?

Answer (score 2):

I dont have your `timer.js` so a "HELLO" is displayed instead. When the first plot is recalculated a progress is displayed. It is not displayed for the second plot.

```
runApp(list(ui = fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),

  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar with a slider input
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput('n', 'Number of obs', 100),
      conditionalPanel("$('#plot').hasClass('recalculating')",
                       id='progressIndicator',
                       "Calculating...",
                       div(id='progress',"HELLO")
      ),
      numericInput('m', 'Second set Number of obs', 100)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput('plot'),
      plotOutput('plotA')
    )
  )
),
server = function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({ Sys.sleep(4)
                              hist(runif(input$n)) 
  })
  output$plotA <- renderPlot({ hist(runif(input$m)) })
}
)
)
```